# Using dplyr to perform functions per row using colnames to group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am really new to dplyr and generally only use base R.

I have been trying to figure out how to compute several statistics per row and havent managed it yet, this differs from the other questions as I'm trying to calculate the whole row - or even better select several columns per row to calculate stats on.

Example1:

A matrix of counts with sample names in the columns

input:

```
cont1 cont2 cont3
1      2     3
55     67    25
```

output:

```
cont1 cont2 cont3 contAVG
1      2     3    2
55     67    25
```

First problem was converting the DF to numeric, I include this incase I'm missing a simpler solution.

```
data_cont %>% 
   mutate_each(funs(as.character)) %>% 
   mutate_each(funs(as.numeric)) %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(avg= mean(.))
```

Here I'm just hoping to get a row mean across all columns, I'd want to compute several different stats ideally ie min,max,sd for each row.

Example 2

The original table contains multiple different conditions, 200+ columns ie.

input:

```
contV1 wtV3 contV4 wtV5 trV8 trV9 ...... contV180
1       4     2     0     66   89           289
```

output:

```
contV1 wtV3 contV4 wtV5 trV8 trV9 ...... contV180 contAVG wtAVG trAVG
1       4     2     0     66   89           289      x      y     z
```

Is it possible to calculate stats per row over different columns using matches to group them without splitting into smaller matrices? This would result in a final matrix with 3 extra columns showing the averages of all cont/wt/tr samples.

I realise I can use `apply()` from base R but I'm really hoping there is a more efficient way using dplyr.

Comment: For just the overall mean per row, use `rowMeans`. For more complicated stuff, I guess you could look into `?select` different helper functions such as `starts_with`, `matches`, `contains` and etc. which will help you to operate on the correct columns. Though I doubt that any row wise operations will be efficient. If all your columns are numeric, it is better to work on a matrix and then even `apply` will be efficient. Though the best option is the `matrixStats` package which has functions such as `rowMins`, `rowMaxs`, `rowSds` and etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David, as far as I know the select function will subset the table like i have done already. If there are no better ways I'll stick with apply.